# Angular Azure AD Msal broadCastService msal:loginTokenSuccess not working

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I am having an problem where the broadcastService is not trigger the msal:loginTokenSuccess. The callback is never triggered.

I got MSAL configured on my angular application. When I login at the Azure AD portal, the broadcastService for "msal"loginSuccess" and "msal:loginFailure always works. However, the broadcastService for msal:loginTokenSuccess never works.

After I authenticated at the Azure portal, I call the acquireTokenSilently() to get the access token.

Even if I already authenticated and my azure ad info is stored in my localStorage, I  want to know that the user is authenticated and got an active token whenever the user reopens the page without having to authenticate at the portal.

Here is my code so far,

I trigger the login with MsalGuard in the app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'landingPage', component: LandingPageComponent, data: { title: 'LandingPage' }, canActivate: [MsalGuard]        },
]
```

or just click on the Login menu which calls

```
login(): void {
    this.msalService.loginRedirect();
  }
```

when the user is redirected back to the LandingPage, I call the following to get the access token

this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(environment.scope, environment.authority )
    .then(token => {

```
  this.access_token = token;
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('error getting access token: ' + error);
    return Promise.resolve('');
});






ngOnInit(): void {
this.loginTokenSuccessSubscription = this.broadCastService.subscribe("msal:loginTokenSuccess", (payload) => {

    })
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show the code where you are triggering login and how you are triggering it.

Comment: Hi, Just added my code that triggers the login

Comment: AquireTokenSilent is to refresh tokens of which you already got from redirect login. What are you trying to do? and what do you need the token for? Is it to get a token to access an API ?

Comment: I am having an problem where the broadcastService is not trigger the msal:loginTokenSuccess. The callback is never triggered. I would like to know when the token is acquired every time the user enters the landing page. After the first time the user authenticates at the portal, he does not need to enters his credentials again but Msal always makes silent calls. I want to know when the token is success.

Comment: what are the environment.scope, environment.authority  you are using with aquireTokenSilent ? as values I mean.

Comment: the authority is 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantGUID' and my scope is   api://myGUID/Data.Read openid

Comment: I can't replicate it however,keep in mind that aquiretokensilent will not do a token request if you already have a valid one for the same scope so probably broadcasting will not fire in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can find another way to check if the token is active with a different event.

Comment: When I first authenticate at the Azure AD portal with the consent, I see the id and access token is returned in localstorage. The broadcastService loginSuccess is triggered but never the loginTokenSuccess. Just wonder why? regardless of the acquireTokenSilent.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the broadcast before acquireTokenSilent ?